# Вылетает приложение при выполнении get-запроса к серверу в потоке

Tags: android

Во fragment в потоке выполняются get-запросы. При переходе во fragment переодически вылетает приложение при выполнении одной из строчек: final Response responseN = requestInterface.getInfo(N).execute();

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static RequestInterface requestInterface;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Object> items;

    public MyFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

        requestInterface = Controller.getApi();

        items = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    try {
                          final Response response1 = requestInterface.getInfo(1).execute();
                          final Response response2 = requestInterface.getInfo(2).execute();
                          ...
                          final Response response100 = requestInterface.getInfo(100).execute();
                          getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                items.add(response1.body());
                                items.add(response2.body());
                                ...
                                items.add(response100.body());
                                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });
        t.start();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-20
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment{99005b0} not attached to 
Activity at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:608)
at MyFragment$2.run(MyFragment.java:120)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну очевидно, что при выполнении вашего потока он обращается к методу `getResources()`, и при каком-то из обращений ваш фрагмент уже не привязан к активити. Вот похожая англоязычная тема: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919240/fragment-myfragment-not-attached-to-activity).

Т.е. при вызове `getResources()` нужно делать еще и проверки:

```
if(isAdded()){
    getResources().....;
}
```

А ваш код... Если у вас там реально 100 строк... Оберните их все в цикл, зачем вы так делаете? (Оберните примерно так):

```
// вместо этого чего-то страшного
final Response response1 = requestInterface.getInfo(1).execute(); 
....
final Response response100 = requestInterface.getInfo(100).execute(); 

// выполняйте запросы так
Response responses[] = new Response[100];
for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; ++i) {
    responses[i] = requestInterface.getInfo(i + 1).execute();
}

// складывайте в коллекцию так
for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; ++i) {
    items.add(responses[i].body());
}
```

Возможно, у вас что-то не получалось с циклами, так в `run()` можно читать лишь из переменных `final` или `effectively final`. Первое означает по сути константу, а второе - переменную, которой просто задают значение единожды. В том примере, что я вам написал, все должно работать, ибо переменной `responses` задается значение лишь один раз. Для верности, конечно, можете пометить ее как `final`.

Comment: selya, в строке 120 у меня: final Response response34 = requestInterface.getInfo(34).execute();

Comment: @Anna13 и не лень было писать 100 одинаковых строк?) Если бы мне было надо, я бы сделал скрипт на js, который сгенерировал бы мне 100 таких строк))0). А если  серьезно. то я не знаю, что у вас там конкретно в `requestInterface.getInfo(34).execute();`, но очевидно, что где-то там кто-то трогает ресурсы

Comment: selya, если пробовать делать циклом и данные сохранять в массиве, то ничего не получается (чтобы не писать 100 строк кода)

Comment: @Значит вы что-то делаете не так. Сейчас в ответ добавлю, как примерно это сделать